# Neo4J Docker Image Takes Too Long to Start

Tags: docker, neo4j

I've noticed that Neo4J Enterprise docker image is taking a lot of time to actually startup.

[image]

In this example you can see that it takes over 13 minutes just to start. Also, in this example, I've done a clean start, meaning I've deleted all data (databases and transactions).

This is the command I'm running:

> docker run --name Neo4J 
> -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 
> -d 
> -v C:/Docker/Neo4J/data:/data:z 
> -v C:/Docker/Neo4J/logs:/logs:z 
> -v C:/Docker/Neo4J/plugins:/plugins:z 
> -v C:/Docker/Neo4J/data/backups:/data/backups:z 
> --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/11111111 
> --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=5G 
> --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=5G 
> --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=5G 
> --env NEO4J_dbms_ssl_policy_bolt_client__auth=NONE 
> --env NEO4J_dbms_ssl_policy_https_client__auth=NONE 
> --env NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes 
> --env NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true 
> --env NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true 
> --env NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true 
> --env NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc"]' 
> neo4j:4.4-enterprise

Right now I'm running this on a Windows machine (Dell XPS 15 - i9 13900H with 64GB Ram) so machine wise I don't see any bottlenecks. In the past I've ran this on a Mac and sometimes it would also be slow to startup but not this frequent.

Does anybody ever has this issue? What have you done to solve it?

Regards!